# Image array with onchange

Tags: javascript, arrays, onchange

A question for you guys, lets say i have an image array and an onchange function in html. Is it possible to lets say option 1 to choose picture 1 to be shown. Option 2 to choose picture 2 to be shown etc etc.
I need to do it in javascript code. If its possible how? any help would be appreciated

```
var imgArray = new Array(3);
                imgArray[0] = new Image();
                imgArray[0].src = "123.jpg";

                imgArray[1] = new Image();
                imgArray[1].src = "1234.jpg";

                imgArray[2] = new Image();
                imgArray[2].src = "12345.jpg";



 <select id="choose_img" onChange "...">
    <option value="0">otpion 1</option>
    <option value="1">option 2</option>
    <option value="2">option 3</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the value of the `select` element and get the according array item using the value as the index.

I have created a simple jsbin for you: http://jsbin.com/notuyobamu/1/edit